# Portable ssh/sftp/scp server for Windows

Tags: windows, server, ssh, portable, sftp

Is there a portable SSH server? By portable I mean:

- It doesn't need to install/configure or anything like that.
- It comes with its own hardcoded public/private keys so I don't need to setup anything (it doesn't need to be truly secure, just very, very portable and easy to run).

Something like `run_sftp_server --root . --port 1234` and then I am able to connect with FileZilla, I download my files and then turn it off.

I don't want to setup public/private keys, run at as daemon or anything else like that.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [Syncplify.me MicroServer!](https://syncplify.me/other_syncplify_software). It fits all requirements in your description.
Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of this software.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Rebex Tiny SFTP Server](https://www.rebex.net/tiny-sftp-server/). Just unzip it and run. It's free even for commercial purposes.

You can configure it a bit, but it's not needed if you don't want to.